# How to dynamically open a div without changing other divs' location

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this layout and I'm trying to open the `options` divs without moving the `buttons` divs. Any idea how to do that?

[JSFiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/o2gxgz9r/23/)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#btn1").click(function() {
    $("#options1").toggle();
  });
  $("#btn2").click(function() {
    $("#options2").toggle();
  });
  $("#btn3").click(function() {
    $("#options3").toggle();
  });
});
```

```css
.btn {
  width: 100px;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  height: 30px;
  display: inline-block;
}
.cont {
  display: inline-block;
}
.options {
  width: 200px;
  height: 150px;
  background: green;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="cont">
  <div id="btn1" class="btn">button 1</div>
  <div id="options1" class="options"></div>
</div>
<div class="cont">
  <div id="btn2" class="btn">button 2</div>
  <div id="options2" class="options"></div>
</div>
<div class="cont">
  <div id="btn3" class="btn">button 3</div>
  <div id="options3" class="options"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/rayon_1990/o2gxgz9r/25/

Comment: only one div display . all  click div display ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's Simple add `position: absolute` to the options class

```
.options{
  position:absolute;
  width: 200px;
  height: 150px;
  background: green;
  display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just set a fixed width to your container and set `overflow: visible;`. This way, your toggle divs width will not effect the width of their parent div without using `position: absolute;`. [See MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow) for more information about overflow.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#btn1").click(function() {
    //$("#options2").css("display", "block");
    $("#options1").toggle();
  });
  $("#btn2").click(function() {
    //$("#options2").css("display", "block");
    $("#options2").toggle();
  });
  $("#btn3").click(function() {
    //$("#options2").css("display", "block");
    $("#options3").toggle();
  });
});
```

```css
.btn {
  width: 100px;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  height: 30px;
  display: inline-block;
}
.cont {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  overflow: visible;
}
.options {
  width: 200px;
  height: 150px;
  background: green;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="cont">
  <div id="btn1" class="btn">button 1</div>
  <div id="options1" class="options"></div>
</div>
<div class="cont">
  <div id="btn2" class="btn">button 2</div>
  <div id="options2" class="options"></div>
</div>
<div class="cont">
  <div id="btn3" class="btn">button 3</div>
  <div id="options3" class="options"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

try this one

```
.btn{
 width: 100%;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  height: 30px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.cont{
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
}

.options{
  width: 100%;
  height: 150px;
  background: green;
  display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could just give `.cont` a position relative and give `.options` a position absolute. That way the options panel starts with the corresponding button.

```
.cont{
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

.options{
  width: 200px;
  height: 150px;
  background: green;
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
}
```